# Intuitive affirmation on convex sets

Tags: general-topology, geometry, convex-analysis

Let $D_1, D_2$ two open, bounded and convex domain in $R^n$. Suppose that $D_2 \supset \overline{D_1}$, and the boundaries of these sets are of class $C^1$.

Fix $x \in \partial D_1$ and suppose that the hiperplane $\{x = (x_1,...,x_n) \in R^n  ; x_1 = 0\}$ is tangent at $x$ and $D_1 \subset \{x = (x_1,...,x_n) \in R^n  ; x_1 < 0\} $

Clearly we can find $y_x \in A:= \partial D_2 \cap \{ z ; (z-x).e_1 >0\}$ such that

$$ max_{z \in A} (z-x).e_1 = (y_x - x). e_1$$

Intuitively $y_x = (\alpha,0,...,0)$ for some $\alpha \in R$ and the hyperplane tanget at $y_x$ is paralalel to the hiperplane $\{x = (x_1,...,x_n) \in R^n  ; x_1 = 0\}$. This is true?

I made these questions because appears that these intuitive affirmations is used in the proof of the lemma 2.2 of this paper

[Existence of classical solutions to a free boundary problem for the p-Laplace operator, (I)](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/228786919_Existence_of_classical_solutions_to_a_free_boundary_problem_for_the_p-Laplace_operator(I)_the_exterior_convex_case) by A. Henrot and H. Shahgholian

I dont know how to prove .. I believe that is the thing of the type: intuitive  to see and hard to prove.

Someone could help me, please?

thanks in advance

Comment: What does $(z - x).e_1 > 0$ mean? Does $.$ denote the inner product?

Comment: Yes =)   . you're right